# Can you explain this python use of square brackets?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Could someone help me understand this piece of code from the beautifulsoup3 documentation? In particular I don't understand the part in square brackets. The code is from this url: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html
I do not understand the square brackets because I thought square brackets were for making lists, does its contents create a list? Also, it doesn't seem to be assigning the list to anything. What does is the purpose of having square brackets and not assigning them to anything? Also, I don't understand this component: `text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)`, but I think I might be able to figure that part out on my own.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup("""1<!--The loneliest number-->
                        <a>2<!--Can be as bad as one--><b>3""")
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
print soup
# 1
# <a>2<b>3</b></a>
```

Okay, so it's for list comprehension, so, a list is being made? But not being used? Why would they do this? Also, when and why would you put anything before the word "for"? as they do down there. Normally I see "for" at the beginning, with nothing prior to it. Also, thank you for the great explanation of the lambda function, I knew it made some sort of mini function but I wasn't quite familiar with it yet, it helped to see how you re-wrote it as a normal function.

Comment: The line with the square brackets is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: oh weird, i just tried this:`[print("stuff") for x in range(0,10)] ` and it worked, so a "side effect" of list comprehension square brackets is that you can make one line for loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part in square brackets is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - basically a short way to create a list.

The reason it is not assigned to anything is that it is not needed here. `extract()` method is called for every found comment and it would delete each comment in a loop. It is actually very confusing, much better would be to write it the following way:

```
for comment in comments:
    comment.extract()
```

---

To understand what `soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))` does you need to understand two key things:

- according to the `text` argument's documentation:

> text is an argument that lets you search for NavigableString objects
>   instead of Tags. Its value can be a string, a regular expression, a
>   list or dictionary, True or None, or a callable that takes a
>   NavigableString object as its argument

Note that, most importantly for us here, is that the value of `text` argument can be a `callable`, or, in other words, a function.

- now that `lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)` is a special syntax for writing anonymous functions in Python. It is the same as you would have:

  ```
  def my_function(text):
      return isinstance(text, Comment)
  ```

What it does is it checks every `NavigableString` object to be an instance of a `Comment` class. In other words, checks if the text it has found is an HTML comment.

---

As a side note, do not spend time on `BeatifulSoup3` as it is not maintained and is not supported anymore, switch to [`BeautifulSoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: +1 list comprehension should not be used for sideeffects

Comment: So, what are these side effects you are talking about?